# How to recognize multiple lexical errors in an input string (using flex)?

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am using flex to generate a lexical analyser for a custom language. The problem I am having is that as soon as I find a misformed token... I have no way to tell what other tokens follow this one. e.g.

```
int v1,v2;
v1=10;v2=20;
v1=v2+1v;
print(v1);
~return;
```

Here, the stream of tokens will be id,<,>,id,<;>...... the language specifies that each token be seperated by a whitespace. So seeing a v after 1 should produce an error and the scanner has to print that error. After that, there are more legal tokens and another illegal token (~return). How do I process the rest of the legal tokens and print the second error.
I am using flex as the scanner generator. When I find that none of the regular expressions for the lexeme matches, I call an error routine that prints the appropriate message.

How do I resume processing after calling this routine?

Comment: good question...  I'd take a look at the generated lexer to see if there are any variables that keep track of the scanner's location or methods to start scanning at a specified location...

Answer (score 2):

Put the white space into the grammar if it's syntactically significant. If it isn't, as it doesn't appear to be here, just ignore the rule. Whitespace is only syntactically significant where it is required to separate tokens, e.g. in `int a;`.

For example, COBOL has a rule that a period must be followed by a white space except in a PICTURE string. Implementing the rule was harder than ignoring it, so I ignored it. It passed FIPS certification, and nobody ever noticed, over about ten years that the compiler was in production use.

NB The best way to handle illegal characters is as parser errors. That way the parser can apply its error recovery strategy. At the lexical level the best you can does print and ignore them.

In lex/flex, this just amounts to having a final rule that reads:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, but it is all I could come up with.
[The Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/User-Values.html)
says you have access to [YY_BUFFER_STATE](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/doxygen/structyy__buffer__state.html).

You *might* be able to use the current position in the file, gotten from the member yy_input_file in YY_BUFFER_STATE, in conjunction with yyrestart(File *f) to resume parsing just after the point of the error.

Again, it seems like there has to be a better solution.